# Why python2.7 import "from tensorflow.python.util import nest " failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, importerror

i used python2.7 is failed

in python2.7

```
>>> from tensorflow.python.util import nest 
Traceback (most recent calllast): 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
ImportError: cannot import name nest
```

but I try to use python3.5 to run `from tensorflow.python.util import nest` is ok

Comment: Have you installed tensorflow for python2? That it is importable in python3 only means you have installed it for that installtion, the python2 installation is completely independant from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run that import statement without any issues on python 2.7. Perhaps your python 2 install is wonky or your tensorflow is out of date (I'm running `0.12.0-rc1`).

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  1 2016, 21:24:23) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
>>> from tensorflow.python.util import nest 
>>>
```

Comment: The current version is 0.12, you should upgrade and try again.